# File Not Found When Launching TreasureHunt

Tags: ios, iphone, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am following the Google Developer's guide for building a virtual reality application for the iPhone. I followed the initial steps and believe I have everything that is necessary installed. When I try to build the app from Xcode on my iPhone, I receive the file not found error on the "#import "GCSCardboardView.h"" statement in the TreasureHuntRenderer.h file. Am I missing a file or has the name of this library changed since the guide was published?

Thanks.